# SQL Server Pivot with Date Ranges as Columns

Tags: sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I have a table with the following structure recording employees arrival and dispersal times:

[image]

What I'm hoping to achieve in a query/stored procedure is a pivot type data return between date ranges as per bottom grid on the attached image.

Could I kindly ask your expertise or sample on how to get it done? I have been researching however all my efforts have been fruitless.

Comment: Will you ever have multiple entries for each `userid`/`DateIn` combination?  Are you looking for a dynamic solution or will you know your dates ahead of time?

Comment: Hello bluefeet indeed multiple entries per userid / DateIn - the date ranges may be selected by the user so I am assuming dynamic is the correct answer.

Comment: If I may add I believe the pivot function is not available in sql 2000 which has been the main cause of my demise :P I am currently working on a crosstab query solution.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server 2000?

Comment: Yeah I understand that's where the problem is sadly :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the PIVOT function to get the final result but since you are aggregating a `string`/`time` value, then you will also need to use a windowing function like `row_number()` to return multiple rows for each `userid`/`datein` combination.

I would use a subquery similar to the following to return your data with a unique sequence number for each `userid`/`datein` combo:

```
select name, 
    datein = convert(varchar(10), datein, 120), 
    dttime = cast(timein as varchar(5)) + ' - '+ cast(timeout as varchar(5)),
    row_number() over(partition by userid, datein order by datein) seq
from dbo.yourtable;
```

Once you have this data, then you can easily apply the pivot:

```
select name, [2013-04-10]
from
(
    select name, 
        datein = convert(varchar(10), datein, 120), 
        dttime = cast(timein as varchar(5)) + ' - '+ cast(timeout as varchar(5)),
        row_number() over(partition by userid, datein order by datein) seq
    from dbo.yourtable
) d
pivot
(
    max(dttime)
    for datein in ([2013-04-10])
) piv;
```

Then if you have an unknown number of values, then you will want to use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE 
    @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @startdate datetime,
    @enddate datetime,
    @paramdef nvarchar(max)

set @startdate = '2013-02-01'
set @enddate = '2013-05-10';
set @paramdef = '@startdate datetime, @enddate datetime';

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(convert(varchar(10), datein, 120)) 
                    from dbo.yourtable
                    where datein > @startdate
                        and datein <= @enddate
                    group by datein
                    order by datein
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = N'SELECT name, '+ @cols + '
            from 
            (
                select name, 
                    datein = convert(varchar(10), datein, 120), 
                    dttime = cast(timein as varchar(5)) + '' - ''+ cast(timeout as varchar(5)),
                    row_number() over(partition by userid, datein order by datein) seq
                from dbo.yourtable
                where datein > @startdate
                    and datein <= @enddate
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(dttime)
                for datein in ('+@cols+')
            ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query, @paramdef, @startdate = @startdate, @enddate = @enddate;
```

Comment: Just out of pure curiosity. How does the windowed function (row_number) elminate the problem which would occur if strings are aggregated? Thanks

Comment: @Kiril When you are aggregating a string/date or something that needs to use `max`/`min`, then you will only end up returning one value for each item you are grouping on.  By creating a unique sequence based on the `datein`/`userid` when the group by is applied you will return multiple rows of data.

Comment: I have in the meantime moved the db to sql 2005 and it worked perfect. bluefeet thanx for all your effort and time invested to assist.

Answer (score -1):

I would add a DISTINCT on the following line:

```
select @cols - select @cols = stuff((select DISTINCT ',' + ....
```